Excel automatically re-opens after closing
When I export MS Project data to Excel I employ a series of statements that open Excel via either: Set xl = GetObject(,"Excel.application") or
Set xl = CreateObject(,"Excel.application")
My declaration is:
Public xl As Excel.Application
I set xl.Visible = False so the export proceeds in the background. At the end of execution, I set the xl.Visible = True to display the result and then Set xl = nothing before exiting the macro code. I either save the created Workbook or review the results and then close the Workbook via either the Close X in the upper right corner or File > Close. So far, so good. But then a few seconds later Excel pops open again as a new instance. Why does that happen?
I thought "clearing" the created object (i.e. Set xl = nothing) would create a clean exit from Excel and/or closing the created file would effectively close any instance of Excel but apparently something is causing a new instance to be created.

When you used Set xl = nothing you only cleared the object reference form memory. In order to close the session you must use xl.Quit... After closing the workbook and before clearing the memory.

Thanks but that doesn't work. The macro finishes (i.e. End Sub) and the created Workbook is open so the user can do whatever they want, save or delete. The problem is when that Workbook is closed, a new instance of Excel pops open again.

Who said a new instance of Excel? Please, read again my above comment. If you only close the workbook, Excel session does not quit. You have to quit it as I suggested above. The excel empty window you see after closing the workbook is the same session EMPTY window...

You said to use xl.Quit after closing the workbook. Except there is no active VBA code to use xl.Quit, the macro is done, all that remains is the open Workbook. The last two statements in the macro are: Set xl = Nothing, followed by End Sub. I've used this sequence for years and I don't recall having this issue. Am I missing something?

If you do not quit in code inserting xl.Quit between wb.Close False and Set xl = nothing, you cannot quit Excel existing session. If you close the workbook manually you should do the same with the session, too. This is not a new session. If you want it to automatically quit after closing the workbook, independent of the way you use, you should use Workbook_BeforeClose event where to place the Application.Quit code line...

I guess I need some education. When I open Excel manually (no VBA) I create an instance of the app. I create a new Workbook and close it (or save it and then close). Once closed, that instance of Excel doesn't pop open again. So why is creating an instance of Excel via VBA different? Why do I now need an event to quit the app?

Nothing to be educated... I missed that you do not close the workbook, you close the application (pressing the top right window X). I thought you only close the workbook (as you said), using File - Close, but I missed the part related to "how you do it"... So, it is strange, indeed. Now, let us differentiate the first supposition. Please, add the next code line in the existing workbook before closing it: Debug.Print Application.hwnd. Note the return handle and close he workbook (in fact the Application) as you do. Then insert  new workbook, write the same code line and run it.

Do the second handle match the first one? If so, we must investigate why the application refuses to quit. If not, please check if there are other hidden workbooks like add-ins, personal.xlsb etc. When a workbook has an unknown problem, VBA start a new session showing the recuperated workbook. If it is not visible, you cannot see it. Just a supposition...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I am driving now...

FaneDuru. If you want to continue, see the chat discussion.
